# CIK Number and Jurisdiction details - Private companies

Tags: data-request, usa, data.gov, state, federal

Can you please suggest on how to get the CIK number and jurisdiction details of private companies registered in the US? What I have is a list of companies and its address, but in need of CIK and Jurisdiction for downloading returns. Open source or paid is fine with me.